# Creating a cursor by name doesn't compile?

Tags: gtkmm3

The doc says "The recommended way to create cursors is to use gdk_cursor_new_from_name()", but when i try :

```
#include <gdkmm/cursor.h>
...
Gdk::Cursor m_hand_cursor = Gdk::Cursor::new_from_name("pointer");
...
```

I get this error:

```
error: ‘new_from_name’ is not a member of ‘Gdk::Cursor’
Gdk::Cursor m_Hand_Cursor = Gdk::Cursor::new_from_name("pointer");
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should consult the [GTKMM documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGdk_1_1Cursor.html#a8f666ad52a4dbbc84b545d82f105e60b), not the C GTK documentation, if you want to use the GTKMM API...

```
Gdk::Cursor::Create(Gdk::Display::get_default(), "pointer");
```